# Removing Deleted Items given loose string matching on sender

Tags: vba, outlook

I wish to create a VBA program to remove items within the `Deleted Items` folder of my outlook. However, I only wish to remove such items from the certain users through matching a loose string.

For example, deleting all emails within the `Deleted Items` box from any user with address like `"Plan_Group_"`, given I may receive emails from  `"Plan_Group_1"`, `"Plan_Group_2"`,`"Plan_Group_3"`,...etc.

At present this is what I have for deletion, but it is for all items within the `Deleted Items` box:

```
Sub RemoveAutomaticItemsInDeletedItems()
    Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long
    'Obtain a reference to deleted items folder
    Set oDeletedItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
    Set oItems = oDeletedItems.Items
    For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        oItems.Item(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I extend this to only look for emails that loosely match a from address string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `If` statement to check the email address:

```
If TypeName(oItems.Item(i)) = "MailItem" And oItems(i).SenderEmailAddress Like "Plan_Group_*" Then
    oItems.Item(i).Delete
End If
```

Or:

```
If TypeName(oItems.Item(i)) = "MailItem" And Left$(oItems(i).SenderEmailAddress, 11) = "Plan_Group_" Then
    oItems.Item(i).Delete
End If
```

Just 2 ways of doing it

Comment: The error I get on the line with `.SenderEmailAddress` is: `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: You need to make sure that `oItems.Item(i)` is actually a `MailItem` for it to work

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, perfect solution

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that check for future reference